# CSS Vertically centering text in a float for a navbar

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment, navbar

I'm trying to create a navigation bar in html+css that looks like the image in the following link:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4ljN.png

Basically I have some large text in the left floated rectangle/div in gray and a list of links in a smaller font in the right floated rectangle/div in red and I would like that text to be centered vertically without having to resort to getting rid of the floats and adjusting margin-left/margin-right of the gray and red boxes. Is this possible and if so, how can it be done?

Comment: I would be great help if you share what you have done so far

Comment: Please check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmHBX/1/)... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems quite hard to vertically aling text in a div.

The trick is to the following.

Suppose the following HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
<p id="child"> text</p>
</div>
```

Now you can vertically align the text by doing the following trick.

```
#parent{
    display: table;
    ....
 }

 #child{
    display: talble-cell;
    vertical-align: center;
 }
```

Doing this leads to the following result.
http://jsfiddle.net/RLchH/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you know the height of the red container, then its easy. Give the **HTML** this way:

```
<div class="red">
    <a href="Home">Home</a>
    <a href="...">...</a>
    <a href="etc.">etc.</a>
</div>
```

And the **CSS** as:

```
.red {line-height: 50px; vertical-align: middle; background: #f00; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align: center; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold;}
.red a {color: #fff; text-decoration: none;}
```

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmHBX/1/)! Hope it helps! :)